# Infinite games: are they well defined?

Tags: lo.logic, soft-question, game-theory, infinite-games

It is just my curiosity about [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31936/) where we have an infinite game and (according to the answers) winning strategies for both players. I am familiar with terminating games only, and I am pretty sure that nonterminating ones can cause many paradoxes. As this is a community wiki mode, I would be happy to see formal definitions, existence of wining strategies as well as possible collisions.

Thanks in advance for keeping my mind finite!

Comment: I was about to ask something like this. :-)

Comment: Wadim, you may want to take a look at the following paper by Bollobas, Leader, and Walters, where an example is giving of a ("continuous") game where both players have winning strategies: http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2524
For "discrete" games, set theory has studied infinite games for a while, and they are an essential tool in modern research. A book like Jech's "Set Theory" should give you a nice overview.

Comment: Related MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23375/building-sets-functions-by-playing-games/23377#23377

Comment: I don't see how they could both have winning strategies, infinite or not: if they both use their winning strategy, the sequence of points is well-defined, and either it converges in $D^{2}$ or it doesn't.

Comment: BlueRaja's comment is correct if the sequence of moves is well-ordered, because then you can define the play of one strategy against another by induction along that well-ordering.  But when the set of moves is not well-ordered, as in the "continuous" games mentioned by Andres Caicedo, then there may not exist a play of the game in which both players follow their strategies.  In such a case, they might both have winning strategies.

Comment: Thanks everybody for valuable comments! @Andres, I wonder whether I get a chance in the nearest year to follow the book (but I promise to have it on my desk!) but the arXiv preprint is a really nice piece (why don't you answer?!). @Joel, your answer there is indeed very nice (plus having Eve and Adam as players is remarkable). @Raja and Andreas, I remain not convinced: both players in an infinite game follow wining strategies and on each finite step (even in the discrete situation) it is hard to agree on who wins! In that special game, the epsilon-delta language can possibly give a solution.

Comment: Actually Wadim, I think the conclusion of the question was that even though it it appears that $P$ has a winning strategy actually the proofs given were flawed and $L$ does. It turns out this is not a case of there being "winning strategies for both players". However, this doesn't mean that there isn't another game where both players have winning strategies.

Comment: In the case of the PL game I carefully followed the reference. I am now convinced that L has a wining strategy and P does not, and the example is especially nice as it helps to prove a nontrivial analytic theorem.

Comment: Wadim, I recently gave a talk aimed at graduate students on the subject of games, particularly on infinite games. You may find it at my page, http://andrescaicedo.wordpress.com/talks/

Comment: Andres, thanks for the link to your interesting talk!

Answer (score 14):

A relatively general definition of an infinite, discrete "Gale–Stewart game" is the one used in Martin's proof of Borel determinacy [1]. More information about this type of game can be found in Kechris's *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* and in Jech's *Set Theory*.

**Definition.** We define a game $G(X,P)$ based on a nonempty set $X$ and a set $P \subseteq X^\omega$. The elements of $X$ are the *moves* of the game. A *play* of the game is a sequence $r = (r_0, r_1, r_2, \ldots)$. If $r \in P$ then we say that player I wins, otherwise we say that player II wins. Hence every play of the game has a winner. The informal interpretation of this game is as follows: player I chooses $r_0$, then player II chooses $r_1$, then player I chooses $r_2$, etc.

The way that the game is played is formally specified by the definition of a winning strategy. In the game $G(X,P)$, a *strategy* is just a function $s \colon \left ( \bigcup_{i \in \omega}X^i \right )  \to X$. Intuitively, the value of $s(\tau)$ is the move that should be played if the other player's moves up this this point are listed in the sequence $\tau$.

A *winning strategy for player I* is a function $f \colon \left ( \bigcup_{i\in\omega} X^{i} \right )  \to X$ such that player I wins any play of the form 
$$
f(\langle \rangle),\: r_1, f(\langle r_1\rangle),\: r_3, f(\langle r_1, r_3\rangle), \ldots
$$

A *winning strategy for player II* is a function $g \colon \left ( \bigcup_{i\in\omega} X^{i+1} \right )  \to X$ such that player II wins any play of the form 
$$
r_0, \: g(\langle r_0\rangle),\: r_2,\: g(\langle r_0, r_2\rangle),\: r_4, g(\langle r_0, r_2, r_4 \rangle),\ldots
$$

---

This set of definitions leads to a well-defined, non-paradoxical collection of games. It is impossible for both players to have a winning strategy for the same game, because the strategies can be played against each other.  However, it is possible for neither player to have a winning strategy, and in fact ZFC proves that in the specific case $X = \{0,1\}$ there is a set $P \subseteq \{0,1\}^\omega$ for which neither player has a winning strategy.

Donald Martin proved the *Borel determinacy theorem* in 1975: if $X$ is any nonempty set whatsoever and $P$ is a Borel subset of $X^\omega$ then one of the players has a winning strategy for $G(X,P)$. Here $X$ has the discrete topology and $X^\omega$ has the product topology.

The *axiom of determinacy* states that if $P$ is any subset of $\{ 0,1 \}^\omega$ then one of the players has a winning strategy in $G(\{0,1\}, P)$. This is inconsistent with ZFC but is consistent with ZF plus dependent choice.

The paper that Andres Caicedo  gave above [2] studies an entirely different type of game, which is continuous rather than discrete.

1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_determinacy_theorem

2: http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2524

Comment: Incidentally, there's no reason that the plays of an infinite ordinal game must be indexed by omega.  Any infinite ordinal lambda will do, though let's just be concerned about countable ordinals here. 

Special care must be taken to know whose turn it is at each play (whose index is some ordinal < lambda).  This is easily accomplished in a "fair" way as long as whose turn it is is defined for limit ordinals; this is not difficult.  (Successor ordinals just follow the alternating turn rule, as for the case lambda = omega.)

Comment: (Cont'd.) Assume "whose turn it is" has been defined for all countable limit ordinals, and hence by alternation for all countable ordinals.  Then it's not even necessary to predefine the length of the game. A simple example is this: let J be any countably infinite set. Each player on their turn claims some member of J.  There must be a first countable ordinal at which the last member of J is claimed: the player who did that is defined as the winner.  (I hope to expand on this soon in a short article.)

Comment: Oops, that should have read, "There must be a first countable ordinal beta at which there are no unclaimed members of J; the player whose turn it is at beta is defined as the winner.

Comment: Daniel, you may be interested in Itay Neeman's work on the determinacy of similar long transfinite games. See his book at http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ineeman/long-games.htm. He an others have also considered games going beyond the countable ordinals. 

Comment: @Carl, thanks a lot for your very detailed formalism and the references. It's an excellent review of the subject. Just a silly question (in view of Andres' example): aren't continuous games a part of this general construction?

Comment: No, I don't view continuous games as part of this construction. For example, the continuous games considered by Bollobás, Leader, and Walters ([2] above) have the property that one cannot "play strategies against each other", and it is possible for both players in those continuous games to have winning strategies. I don't see how to reconcile that with the family of games I defined. 

Comment: Carl, I just wish to draw a distinction (for myself!) between the discreteness and continuity in this particular construction; the additional property you mention can be put as a constraint for a discrete infinite game, can't it? Yes, the theory you describe, with plays being discrete sequences, everything works perfect. What's wrong when plays of a game are functions on $[0,1]$, say? I believe that this should have been studied as well, because of well-studying of the discrete situation. My question is just in the case if you know something on this. Just my curiosity. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware of quite a number of theories of "games" in mathematics. A not-overly-naive preliminary is to ask about what these are, and then what they have in common.

I think the earliest is probably the Polish (Banach-Mazur) type, which have already been defined. "Game theory'' as in von Neumann-Morgenstern is another, important for economists. Combinatorial Game Theory (CGT) is another, with its distinctive ending rule. And then there is the use of "game semantics" in computer science.

The game-like aspect is certainly to do with quantifiers. What mathematicians would recognise as "uniformity" (there exists ... such that for all ...) is to be iterated. My winning is stated in the form "I have a play such that for all plays you make (I have a play such that for all plays you make (...))". This is the typical game quantifier G, and what matters is what happens to the ... . It happens to be true, for example, that any chess game is decided by the time 10,000-ply has been played, so for chess G is a simple iteration, not some sort of "fixed point" construction.

Examples from logic I think largely fall into the "Polish" style of game. That is to judge by the Hodges book on model theory. In CGT there is a no particular distinction between finitary and infinitary games. Whichever theory is being spoken about, you need to explain carefully what the winning or ending condition is, and quite what you mean by a "strategy" (recall that G is sort of non-constructive, being existential in nature).

Comment: Thanks, Charles, for your thoughts. As for "need to explain carefully what the winning or ending condition is" this is exactly the point I tried to get from the author of http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31936/ (in that case there is no ending condition!).

Answer (score 2):

The Axiom of Choice implies that there exist infinite games in which neither player has a winning strategy.  Thus, the Axiom of Choice is incompatible with the [Axiom of Determinacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_determinacy).  An example of a game where neither player has a winning strategy is the following (caveat: I'm not a set-theorist).

The *game* is a subset $G \subset [0,1]$ of real numbers.  At stage 1, player 1 chooses a bit which is either 0 or 1.  At stage 2, player 2 (knowing player 1's choices so far) chooses another bit.  The players then repeat.  After $\omega$ steps, they have constructed a real number $g \in [0,1]$ where the odd bits of $g$ (in binary) are given by player 1's choices and the even bits of $g$ are given by player 2's choices.  Player 1 wins if $g \in G$, and player 2 wins if $g \notin G$.

Regarding the question that inspired the question, I've had a look at the paper (it's available on Springerlink).  I'm convinced that $L$ does have a winning strategy.  So, that particular game *is* determined.

Comment: Each set $G$ leads to a different game. For some sets $G$, the game will be determined (e.g. if $G$ is empty). For other sets, it will not be determined. For example, if $G$ is a "Bernstein set", neither containing nor disjoint from any nonempty perfect closed set, then neither player will have a winning strategy. This is because a winning strategy for player 1 can be used to build a nonempty perfect closed set in $G$, and a winning strategy for player 2 can be used to build a nonempty perfect closed set in the complement.  Bernstein sets can be constructed in ZFC using the axiom of choice. 

Comment: Carl, I won't be too critical to Tony's answer: there could be sets $G$ for which wining strategies do not exist.

Answer (score 2):

In recent years, a relatively abstract and general formulation of extensive form games has been developed by Carlos Alos-Ferrer and Klaus Ritzberger. The formulation is general enough to discuss when some useful properties hold- and when they fail. In particular, in [Trees and Extensive Forms](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022053108000288) (WP version can be found here [here](http://www.univie.ac.at/vwl/Research/FWF/vie0506.pdf)), they give necessary and sufficient conditions for when every pure strategy in an extensive game induces an outcome and when this outcome is unique.

Comment: Michael, sorry for late reaction. I really wonder about how practical are the conditions, but this indeed complements the answers above.